# Omitting spines in a statsmodels mosaic-plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, statsmodels

I would like to plot a mosaic-plot with statsmodels.graphics.mosaicplot.mosaic, but without the "spines" or boundaries drawn. The following is what I thought should work - e.g. for omitting the left spine -, but it doesn't.

```
from statsmodels.graphics.mosaicplot import mosaic
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {'a': 10, 'b': 15, 'c': 16}

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

props = lambda key: {'color': 'w' }

fig, rects = mosaic(data, title='basic dictionary', 
                    properties=props, ax=ax)

ax.spines['left'].set_visible('False')

print(ax.spines['left'].get_visible())
```

I end up with the same result as if I'd omitted the ax.spines().

[image: mwe result]

I'd appreciate somebody pointing me to what's wrong with the above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is of course a difference between `False` and `"False"`. I.e. `print(False == "False")` prints False. And `if "False": print(True)` prints `True` indeed.

In that sense you need to use

```
ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
```

Second. The mosaic consists of 3 axes. So you need to do the above for each of them.

```
for axi in fig.axes:
    axi.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
```

Result:

[image]